# Rails -- Single Table Inheritance -- flawed casting approach?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, single-table-inheritance, duck-typing

So I have been looking into Single Table Inheritance lately, and have found this common question/answer:

> question: how do you change the class of an object `obj` from Alpha to
>   Beta, assuming Beta < Alpha, in STI?
>
> answer: ruby is a duck-typed language, so you don't use casting.  But all you need to do is set the "type" variable to "Beta" and save the object, and the next time you load the Alpha object it will be of type Beta:
>
> ```
> obj = Alpha.new
> obj.save #now obj is of type Alpha
>
> obj.type = "Beta"
> obj.save #now obj is of type Beta
> ```

However, this approach does not seem to work for me.  While obj does correctly save, it doesn't seem to function as a Beta object at all.  It saves without running Beta validations, and when I checked `obj.respond_to?(:beta_method) #beta_method being a method in the beta class`, it returned false.  Does this approach not work?  Is there a correct approach?  Or am I simply doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I found that when I did Alpha.last.respond_to(:beta_method) it returned false, while Beta.last.respond_to(:beta_method) returned true (both Alpha.last and Beta.last returned the same object however).  Interesting development?  Still if someone could explain this in detail (with respect to how ruby handles inheritance) that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, Ruby does not allow typecasting. Rather, what is happening here is that ActiveRecord is instantiating an instance of a different class depending on what the value of the `type` field is. So when you are changing it to "Beta", you aren't really doing anything from Ruby's point of view.

But when ActiveRecord looks in the database to retrieve the record, it sees the new `type` value and instantiates an instance of `Beta` rather than `Alpha`. This process has less to do with Ruby than it does with ActiveRecord in particular.

There are sometimes more elegant approaches depending on your situation. If you need to "convert" a model from one type to another (e.g. an `Employee` becomes a `Manager`, which has additional methods), this is a reasonable way to it. In other cases, your goal might be better achieved by using mixins or some other tool.

You can also create a temporary instance of `Beta` from `Alpha`'s attributes if you need to, like this:

```
# obj is an instance of Alpha
obj = Beta.new(obj.attributes)
```

But this is similarly a weird thing to need to do in most cases.

Comment: I don't think this answer is quite right.  In the OP, `obj.type = "Beta" ; obj.save` really _does_ update the DB, but the in-memory version will sill be typecast as an Alpha.  Doing `obj.reload` won't work in this case because Rails expects it to be an Alpha.  But you can prove it really has changed with: `obj2 = Beta.find(obj.id)`

Comment: ... but even better, use `obj.becomes(Beta)` as @Teoulas describes below.

Comment: I never implied that the database wasn't updated. What I said was that by changing the type to "Beta", Ruby doesn't care (it still has an instance of Alpha); as I said in the next paragraph, when ActiveRecord retrieves the record anew from the database, it will construct a Beta instance. (I don't recall why I didn't mention #becomes in my original post, but as you say, someone else brought it up.)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might want to either use [`becomes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) or change the type of the object like you did (or directly via `update_attribute`) and reload it from the database (or maybe both).

`becomes` will instantiate and return a new object of the class passed as the sole parameter, using the same attributes as the previous object. This will allow you to call methods of the new object. For example:

```
a = Alpha.last

# if you want to save the new type in the database:
a.type = 'Beta' 
a.save

b = a.becomes(Beta)
b.respond_to?(:beta_method)
=> true
```

I have found, that the order in which you call the methods is important. If you try to use `becomes` first and then change the type and save, it doesn't change the type in the database.